Network setting the Ubuntu server 24.04 way
I have a couple of production ubuntu servers that has been do-release-upgrade'd at least 3 times - and now I'm confused about how the network is (supposed) to be configured .... is it /etc/network/interface or via some /etc/netplan/xxxx.yaml thing?
I'd like to get the simplest and reliable way to configure the network... I fired up a new install of 24.04 and it seems that netplan is the default?
So is there a document somewhere about how to tidy up the network config: what do I have to  enable/disable,and which config files do I modify to make a change.
Thanks
